# Docker compose file is invalid

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm am trying to create a healthcheck for two of my images at runtime, but when I set up the first one I get:

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>   Unsupported config option for docker-bench-security: 'healthcheck'

Below are my images

```
$ docker build --rm -t docker-bench-security .
```

Here is my *docker-compose.yml*

```
    version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
  healthcheck:
   test: ["CMD", "ec2-user_db_1"]
```

Info from `docker ps -a`

```
Image:       Command:                            Name: 
mysql:5.7    "docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld"       ec2-user_db_1
wordpress    "docker-entrypoint.sh apache2-foreground"   ec2-   user_wordpress_1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are not giving us the full picture in here, we are missing a crucial information: what is the `version` that begins your `docker-compose.yml`? Mind that the `healthcheck` have been around only for version ^2.1 of docker-compose

Comment: @b.enoit.be Sorry about that version: 3.1

Comment: What does `docker-compose --version` brings you?

Comment: @b.enoit.be docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01

Comment: As you've pasted it, `healthcheck:` is at the same level as `db:` and Docker Compose parses it as a separate service.  Does indenting it one more level help?

Comment: @DavidMaze I still get                                                                                    [WARN] 5.26  - Ensure container health is checked at runtime
[WARN]      * Health check not set: ec2-user_db_1
[WARN]      * Health check not set: ec2-user_wordpress_1                                                after doing that